# Is there a R function to add the count of horizontal bars beside the bars in UpSetR plot?

Tags: r, upsetr

I used the `upset(fromList(x), show.numbers = 'yes',  order.by = 'freq')` query to plot the `UpSetR` plot. But it is showing only the count of vertical bars on the top of vertical bars. I want the count of horizontal bars too. If there is a command to add the count of horizontal bars along with the count of vertical bars then please share the command.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your code appears to be ok, it should have horizontal bars if you have over one variable with missing data (I think you refer to the bars related to the amount of missing data per variable, that's correct?). As you have not included  the plot you got, neither the dataset structure, we cannot contribute to answer your question. It is always a good practice to include in your questions, alongside the code, package info, the outputs and messages, and also at least the data structure...